# Lack of iteration and appending of empty list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

The following code isn't iterating as it should. I don't understand what the problem is. Please advise if you think you might be able to help me.

```
def getRainfallAmounts(namesOfMonths):
    NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12
    totalRainfallList = [ ]
    
    for currentMonthIndex in range(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        monthlyRainfall = float(input("Please enter the rainfall amount for " +\
                                      namesOfMonths[currentMonthIndex]))
        totalRainfallList.append(monthlyRainfall)
        
        return totalRainfallList
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is indented under the `for` loop, so it returns at the end of the first iteration. You should un-indent it so the `for` loop completes and only then return:

```py
def getRainfallAmounts(namesOfMonths):
    NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12
    totalRainfallList = [ ]
    
    for currentMonthIndex in range(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        monthlyRainfall = float(input("Please enter the rainfall amount for " +\
                                      namesOfMonths[currentMonthIndex]))
        totalRainfallList.append(monthlyRainfall)
        
    return totalRainfallList # Here!
```

Comment: Amazing how something so simple can be such a conundrum. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will admit that I don't work much with python (what I'm assuming this is), but your `return` is in the body of the `for` loop, so you effectively finish the loop after (well, technically during) the first iteration.

Unindent the `return` by one level.

Comment: Amazing how something so simple can be such a conundrum. Thank you!